# How find this $t_{n}$ if such $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n+2}{2k+1}t_{k}=n(n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If the sequence $\{t_{n}\}$ is such that 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n+2}{2k+1}t_{k}=n(n+1)$$
>   and $t_{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$, then prove or disprove
>   $$t_{n}=(2n+1)\cdot (2^{2n-2})\cdot B_{2n}$$
>   where $B_{n}$ represents the Bernoulli numbers.

This problem is because when I want to find $\zeta(2n)$, and the last step I have this:
$$\zeta(2n)=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot 2\pi^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}t_{n}$$
where $t_{n}$ is such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{2n+2}{2k+1}t_{k}=n(n+1),
t_{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$.

and we know
$$\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}$$
can see [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function)